# Calling converted string from UIDataPicker date

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

Now I am learning Swift and making a typical ToDo app.
I found a function to convert date data from UIDatePicker to String, here is my ViewController chunk of code:

```
@IBAction func dateToString(sender: UIDatePicker) {
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
            var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
            return ()
        }
```

But the problem is that I can not access the string results from this function, in my app
i have 2 labels in every tableViewCell, one simple label text data, and another is date data from date picker (also should be a string):

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let date =
        item = Item (name: name, date: date)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let item = item {
        nameTextField.text = item.name
                           = item.date

}
```

}

please help, what should I write in

```
let date =
```

and

```
= item.date
```

to define a date?
I've tried to call a function let date = dateToString; but it doesn't work for me.
Greatly appreciate any help here!

Comment: what you trying to do can you put your whole viewController code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function like

```
var strDate:String = String()

@IBAction func dateToString(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
    }
```

Then you can use

```
let date = strDate
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your dateToString function shouldn't be an `IBAction`. Those are used for methods called directly by interface items and hooked up in Interface Builder. What you want here is a regular function that takes a date and returns a formatted string, like this:

```
func dateToString(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Now when you want a formatted date string, you call it and pass it the `Date` you want it to format. It looks like you're using a `UIDatePicker` to specify the date, so you need to set up an `@IBOutlet` in your view controller (if you haven't already done so) to give you access to that object. To do that, control-drag from the date picker to your view controller source, then name the outlet. It will generate code in your source like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

Now you can refer to the datePicker elsewhere in your class. So you can get the date as a formatted string like this:

```
let dateString = dateToString(date: myDatePicker.date)
```

You can then pass this string to an `Item`, or set it as the text of a field or label.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work... 
        
func dateToString (date: date) -> String {
        gives me "Use of undeclared type Date)... how I shall declare it and where?

Comment: @PetroIontsev It works in my test project. What happens when you try it?

Comment: @PetroIontsev Ah that explains it. My code is Swift 3. `Date` is just the new name for `NSDate`. And `DateFormatter` will be `NSDateFormatter`. There may be other changes too, I'm not sure.

Comment: I've resolved the problem, thank you! Edited core for my version of swift

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out:

```
func dateToString (date: NSDate) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            let date = dateToString (myDatePicker.date) ?? ""
            item = Item (name: name, date: date)
        }
```